# Is this example with konigs bipartite graph theorem correct?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

Take example:-

Connections:

1 - 1"

1 - 2"

2 - 2"

2 - 3"

3 - 3"

3 - 4"

4 - 4"

According to konigs theorem maximal matching gives minimum vertex cover but here:

(1-1",2-3",4-4") gives answer 3 with minimum vertex cover while (1-1",2-2",3-3",4-4") maximum matching gives answer 4.

What am i doing wrong in this....
Please help....

Comment: A graph is not bipartite if it contains odd cycles, and "1-1" is odd cycle so your graph is not bipartite.

Comment: @ÖöTiib you're wrong, because OP gave misleading names to vertices - notice that `1 != 1"`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the vertex cover problem, you want to pick set of vertices `V` in such a way that every edge in the graph has at least one endpoint in `V`.

Konig's theorem is the following:

> In any bipartite graph, the number of edges in a maximum matching
>   equals the number of **vertices** in a minimum vertex cover.

In your example, maximum matching is of course 4, but also minimum vertex cover is 4 because you can cover all edges by picking vertices `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and you cannot do better than that.